# SQL Performance on count query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle and all indexes are inserted.

My tables are below :

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  type_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  is_deleted varchar2(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (1,'John',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (2,'Mark',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (3,'Leon',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (4,'David',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (5,'Mike',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (6,'Sam',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (100,'Nike',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (200,'Adidas',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (300,'Reebook',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (400,'Puma',0,'F');
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, type_id, is_deleted) VALUES (500,'Kinetix',0,'F');

CREATE TABLE ROLE
( role_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  role_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ROLE (role_id, role_name) VALUES (10, 'User');
INSERT INTO ROLE (role_id, role_name) VALUES (11, 'Company');

CREATE TABLE ROLE_REL
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  user_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  role_id number(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (1,1, 10);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (2,2, 10);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (3,3, 10);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (4,4, 10);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (5,5, 10);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (6,6, 10);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (7,100, 11);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (8,200, 11);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (9,300, 11);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (10,400, 11);
INSERT INTO role_rel (id,user_id,role_id) VALUES (11,500, 11);

CREATE TABLE COMPANY_USER
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  user_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  company_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  is_deleted varchar2(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (1,1,100,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (2,1,200,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (3,1,300,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (4,3,400,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (5,1,500,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (6,2,100,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (7,3,100,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (8,4,100,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (9,4,200,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (10,5,100,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (11,6,100,'F');
INSERT INTO company_user(id,user_id,company_id,is_deleted) VALUES (12,6,200,'F');

CREATE TABLE CITY
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  city_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO city(id,city_name) VALUES (1,'New York');
INSERT INTO city(id,city_name) VALUES (2,'Sacramento');
INSERT INTO city(id,city_name) VALUES (3,'Washington');
INSERT INTO city(id,city_name) VALUES (4,'New Jersey');
INSERT INTO city(id,city_name) VALUES (5,'Toronto');

CREATE TABLE CITY_USER
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  user_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  city_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  is_deleted varchar2(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (1,1,3,'F');
INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (2,2,4,'F');
INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (3,3,4,'F');
INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (4,4,1,'F');
INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (5,5,1,'F');
INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (6,6,2,'F');
INSERT INTO CITY_USER(id,user_id,city_id,is_deleted) VALUES (7,1,1,'F');

CREATE TABLE BRANCH
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  branch_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO branch(id,branch_name) VALUES (1,'Black');
INSERT INTO branch(id,branch_name) VALUES (2,'White');
INSERT INTO branch(id,branch_name) VALUES (3,'Blue');
INSERT INTO branch(id,branch_name) VALUES (4,'Yellow');
INSERT INTO branch(id,branch_name) VALUES (5,'Orange');

CREATE TABLE BRANCH_USER(
id number(10) NOT NULL,
user_id number(10) NOT NULL,
branch_id number(10) NOT NULL,
is_deleted varchar2(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (1,1,5,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (2,2,1,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (3,3,1,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (4,4,2,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (5,5,3,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (6,6,3,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (7,1,1,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (8,2,3,'F');
INSERT INTO BRANCH_USER(id,user_id,branch_id,is_deleted) VALUES (9,1,3,'F');
```

Below is my query.

```
SELECT count(CU.company_ID) as TypeID, CU.Company_ID, C.Name
FROM Company_User CU
INNER JOIN USERS C
 on CU.Company_ID = c.user_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT Distinct U.user_ID 
    FROM users U
    INNER JOIN Role_Rel RR
    on RR.user_ID = U.user_ID
    WHERE U.is_deleted = 'F'
    and RR.Role_ID = 10) U
 on CU.User_ID = U.user_ID
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Distinct PU.user_ID 
    FROM users PU 
    INNER JOIN city_user SUL  
    on SUL.user_ID = PU.user_ID 
    WHERE sul.city_id = 1 and PU.is_deleted = 'F') PU
    on CU.User_ID = PU.user_ID
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Distinct KU.user_ID 
    FROM users KU 
    INNER JOIN branch_user hd  
    on hd.user_ID = KU.user_ID
    WHERE hd.branch_id = 3 and KU.is_deleted = 'F' and hd.is_deleted = 'F') KU
    on CU.User_ID = KU.user_ID
GROUP BY CU.Company_Id, C.Name
ORDER BY  count(CU.Company_ID) Desc;
```

My result is as i want, Companies are listed as their users count number.

```
TypeID    Company_id     Name
6           100          Nike
3           200          Adidas
2           400          Puma
1           300          Reebok.
```

My result

```
TYPEID  COMPANY_ID  NAME
2       100         Nike
1       500         Kinetix
1       200         Adidas
1       300         Reebook
```

[SQL-FIDDLE is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abce7).

I edited my question according @xQbert answer and I add two new restriction in query according branch_user and city_user tables. How can i modify my question to perform better ?

Imagine all needed indexes are added. I am open to new query or new needed indexes that should be in query. Query solves my problem just i want to make my query to be more optimized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle. I will edit now my question.

Comment: Add table and index definitions etc. Execution plan/explain?

Comment: I don't see a deleted column on table users...  `us.deleted= 'F'` seems invalid given listed structure

Comment: Please add the execution plan as well. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @jarlh i edited my question with indexes, but my question was more about how can i write more optimize query and fast then this one with indexes.

Comment: Why my question is downvoted, cant someone ask how to make is its query more optimize, i explained everythins clearly, i am asking for better query ?

Comment: I see no reason for a downvote at all. I'll give you +1.

Comment: I don't see how your query relates to the data shown. You select a name from users and your results contain 'Adidas' rather than 'John'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i edited my question. I want my query to count how much user are in that company. Company and users are in same table. Their role are different

Comment: @Jo_bast is your query missing a distinct on the order by?

Comment: @xQbert my order query is without distinct should i put distinct too there ? becouse i have SELECT Count (DISTINCT com_user.user_id)

Comment: @Jo_Bast depends on what you want.  If you want the order to match the count(distinct val) in select then yes, otherwise there's a chance the order would not be descending but only if  a user had role 10 multiple times, or if you allowed for multiple roles in the search.

Answer (score 2):

Without indexes, execution plan and table stats impossible to improve we don't have the needed information to evaluate.  Simply put, the question lacks the analysis or information to know what improvements to apply.

I probably would have written it this way...

Can't say if it's any faster or results in a better execution plan though.

```
SELECT count(CU.company_ID) as TypeID, CU.Company_ID, C.Name
FROM Company_User CU
INNER JOIN Company C
 on CU.Company_ID = c.Company_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT Distinct U.user_ID 
            FROM users U
            INNER JOIN Role_Rel RR
              on RR.user_ID = U.user_ID
            WHERE U.deleted = 'F'
              and RR.Role_ID = 10) U
 on CU.User_ID = U.user_ID
GROUP BY CU.Company_Id, C.Name
ORDER BY  count(CU.Company_ID) Desc;
```

Comment: The `select` in the column list was a big potential performance issue, which this answer corrects.

Comment: Agreed, but on a small data set I don't think we'd see much performance difference.  By removing it, we basically eliminate a iterative call of the select to derive each name, and allow the database to operate on in set based operations which allows for a single join instead of multiple select statements.

Comment: @xQbert i have combined company and users table, and put new role in role table, how your query could be rewrited according to this new change ?

Comment: and @xQbert imagine that i have one location_users relation table that consisti user_id, city_id , i just should add new inner join like you have done with role table ? for getting how much shoes are sold in city

Comment: @Jo_Bast.  Please update your question with the new information and sample data; alternatively mock up the structure and data at http://sqlfiddle.com so we can see a working data set and we can provide a working example back.

Comment: @xQbert i update my question according new tables and in question there is SQL-Fiddle code.

Answer (score 0):

You want companies with their distinct user count? Then select from users and join the user counts.

```
select 
  c.company_id, 
  c.companyname,
  cu.users
from company c
join
(
  select company_id, count(distinct user_id) as users
  from company_user
  where user_id in (select user_id from role_rel where role_id = 10)
    and user_id in (select user_id from users where deleted = 'F')
  group by company_id
) cu on cu.company_id = c.company_id
order by cu.users desc;
```

---

Okay, no company table any longer ...

```
select 
  c.user_id as company_id, 
  c.name as companyname,
  cu.users
from 
(
  select * 
  from users 
  where user_id in (select user_id from role_rel where role_id = 11)
  and deleteted = 'F'
) c
join
(
  select company_id, count(distinct user_id) as users
  from company_user
  where user_id in
  (
    select user_id
    from users 
    where user_id in (select user_id from role_rel where role_id = 10)
    and deleteted = 'F'
  )
  group by company_id
) cu on cu.company_id = c.company_id
order by cu.users desc;
```

You can use with clauses instead of direct derived tables if you like that better:

```
with company_data as
(
  select * 
  from users 
  where user_id in (select user_id from role_rel where role_id = 11)
  and deleteted = 'F'
)
, user_data as
(
  select * 
  from users 
  where user_id in (select user_id from role_rel where role_id = 10)
  and deleteted = 'F'
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version using subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  count(DISTINCT user_id) AS type_id, 
  company_id AS id, 
  (
    SELECT name 
    FROM   users 
    WHERE  user_id = com_user.company_id
  ) AS name 
FROM company_user com_user
WHERE 1=1
  -- check that "user_id" is associated 
  -- with role named "User" and this user
  -- was not deleted
  AND user_id IN
  (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM users
    WHERE 1=1
      AND deleted = 'F'
      AND user_id IN
      (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM role_rel 
        WHERE role_id IN (SELECT id FROM role WHERE roleName = 'User')
      )
  )
  -- check that "company_id" is associated 
  -- with role named "Company" and this user
  -- was not deleted
  AND company_id IN
  (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM users
    WHERE 1=1
      AND deleted = 'F'
      AND user_id IN
      (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM role_rel 
        WHERE role_id IN (SELECT id FROM role WHERE roleName = 'Company')
      )
  )
GROUP BY company_id 
ORDER BY count(company_id) DESC
;
```

I don't like that much of retrieving the column `name` using subquery, but I'll try to change it later if this query doesn't work well for you.